# How can I display RouteConfig in Solution Explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I want to be able to see `RouteConfig.cs` in solution explorer.  Right now I have to do a text search to drag the file out of the depths.

How can I display the file which appears to be buried in Global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside a folder called "App_Start" which is at the same level in the folder hierarchy as the `Global.asax` file.  Here's an article that has a nice step-by-step example for discovering the file in Solution Explorer:  [ASP.NET MVC 4: Where Have All The Global.asax Routes Gone?](http://www.jondavis.net/techblog/post/2012/06/23/ASPNET-MVC-4-Where-Have-All-The-Globalasax-Routes-Gone.aspx)